# C, Sorting a queue of structures

Tags: c, sorting, queue, structure

I could use a little help. I'm trying to sort a queue of structures by year.

This are my structures:

```
struct element{

        int id;
        int sign;
        int year;
        int month;
        double amount;

        struct element *next;


    };

struct queue{
    struct element *head;
    struct element *tail;
    struct element *heads;
    struct element *temp;
    struct element *temph;

    int size;
};
```

and this is the function i wrote:

```
void sort(struct queue* queue){

if (queue->size == 0){
        printf("Struct is empty\n");}
else {

        struct element* head=queue->head;
        struct element* heads=queue->heads;
        struct element* temp=NULL;
        struct element* temph=queue->head;
        int i, size=queue->size;        

        for(i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        heads=head->next;
            if((head->year)>(heads->year)){

                temp=head;
                head=heads;
                heads=temp;         
            }


        head=head->next;
        heads=NULL;
        temp=NULL;
        }

head=temph;
}

}
```

It breaks when I copmare: `if((head->year)>(heads->year))`.
I'm pretty sure that my problem is caused by improper reference to the structure next to `head` (I named it `heads`).

Comment: "It breaks" - please be more descriptive.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your intention is to *bubble sort* a linked list?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use bubble sort.

Comment: Than: try to take @david-schwartz's advice: sorting a linked lists implies changing the *pointers* that point to the items. That could be the ->next pointers or the "external" head pointer, that points to the first item.

Comment: @wildplasser, @david-schwartz I'm not sure if I understand completely. The sorting should look like: `temp->next=head->next;`  `head->next=heads->next;`  `heads->next=temp->next;` ?

Comment: Draw it on paper: indeed, *three* pointers have to be changed: the ->next pointers of the two nodes_to_be_swapped plus the pointer that points to the first of them. BTW, IMHO your variable names are confusing (and you have too many varaibles, which is even more confusing)

Comment: @wildplasser so, in loop:
`temp=head;`
`head=head->next;`
`head->next=temp;`

moving to next swap:
`head=head->next;`

Something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I omitted all the non-important stuff, and reduced the linked-list bubbele sort to this skeletton.

```
void sort(struct queue* queue)
{
struct element **pp, *this;

    if (!queue->head ){
        fprintf(stderr, "OMG Struct is empty\n");
        return;
       }

        for(pp = &queue->head; this = *pp; pp = &(*pp)->next){
        struct element *other = this->next;
            if (!this->next) break;
            if (this->year < other->year) continue;
            /* 
            ** Now, Swap this (b) and other (c) 
            ** old situation: @a -> (b) -> (c) -> (d)
            ** new situation: @a -> (c) -> (b) -> (d) 
            */
            *pp = other;              /* @a  -> (c) */
            this->next = other->next; /* (b) -> (d) */
            other->next = this;       /* (c) -> (b) */
        }
/* Note: when we get here, "this" will contain the last non-NULL node in the
** chain, and can be used to reset the tail-pointer
*/
return;
}
```